# React, FF20.0 Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firefox

Users on old FF 20.0, 22.0
the following error occurs, when render `<input />` even if it is empty:

```
Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object.
[17:10:31.350] The above error occurred in the <input> component:
    in input (at RegistrationFormInput.js:39)
 ... stack

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, App.
```

`` 38 <div className="holder-input">
    39  <input`
        className="form-control"
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        id={props.id}
        name={props.name || props.id}
        type={props.type}
        maxLength="255"
        onChange={props.onChange}
        value={props.value}
        autoComplete={props.autoComplete}
      />
    </div> ``

I can not solve it and understand why it occurs, the version of React - `"react": "^16.2.0",`

Has anyone seen one of these and know how to solve it ?

Comment: those versions of firefox are 5 to 6 years old. Much has changed.

Comment: a brief google search suggests it may have to do with some extension - try disabling all extensions - if the problem goes away, try enabling them one by one to see which causes the issue

Comment: there is no extensions

Comment: does it happen with a particular input `type`?

Comment: no, i can just add `<input type="text" />` and catch this error

Comment: OK, so, then, no, it's nothing to do with input type ... seriously, a lot of effort for a 6 year old unsupported very insecure browser